# How to filter JavaScript Objects with multiple criterias

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got a JSON file with recipes.
Now there is a search bar on my homepage where the user can check and uncheck checkboxes to select which attribute of the recipe (name, ingredients, tags, category) he wants to search in. He can also check multiple criteria.

Now I want to filter my object based on the selected criteria.
I know if there is for example only checked the "**name**" I can just go for

```
recipes.filter(e -> e.name.indexOf(searchString) >= 0)
```

But how can I say dynamically "If also the ingredients are checked filter for a found result in the name OR in the ingredients".

I hope you understand. Thank you.

Comment: use `&&` or `||` operator in filter?

Comment: And how do I handle that the checkbox can be checked or unchecked? I don't want to filter both criteria all the time.

Comment: @DannyBergs I don't know your full code ,so any assumption here wont be feasible

Comment: Because the checkboxes are in a form I just create bools based on the value in the URL. 

So you can assume that there are simple booles like "nameIsChecked" "IngredientsIsChcked", "TagsIsChecked" etc.

So if just name is checked I want to filter the name of the recipes.
If also ingredients is checked I want to filter if the searched string is in the name OR in the ingredients

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the attributes in an array and then use `.some()` to check if any of the attributes matches.

```js
const recipes = [
  { name: "pizza", ingredients: "dough tomato mince", category: "meal" },
  { name: "pie", ingredients: "dough sugar", category: "dessert" },
  { name: "stew", ingredients: "potato mince onoin", category: "meal" },
  { name: "donut", ingredients: "sugar", category: "dessert" }
];
// Get these from the checkboxes:
const selected_attributes = [
  "name",
  "ingredients"
];
// Get this from the searchbar:
const seachbar_query = "do";
// Filter all recipes where the name or ingredients contains "do".
// We expect "pizza" and "pie', which contain dough in their ingredients.
// And we also expect "donuts", whose name starts with "do"
const filtered = recipes.filter( recipe => {
  return selected_attributes.some( attribute => {
    return recipe[ attribute ].includes( seachbar_query );
  });
});

console.log( filtered );
```

Comment: thank you, this makes sense to me.
I just have one problem left.
How do I create the "selected_attributes" array?
ATM I just check if the checkbox is checked by save the data,request.get.CHECKBOXNAME and check if its undefined

Comment: Any method. If the checkboxes get POSTed by a form, the name should be there something like: `nameIsChecked=true&IngredientsIsChcked=false`. SO you just have to chaneg the anmes into the actual attributes, so you have `name=true&ingredients=false` instead. Or how exactly are you passing the checkboxes? This is the easy part, so I don not fully understand the issue yet.

Comment: If you create an url with true/false, just also apss the name through the url: `http://myserver/recipes?name&ingredients` or `http://myserver/recipes?name=true&ingredients=true&tags=false&category=false`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am very beginner in js.
The checkboxes are passed with a get method.
So there is something in the url like "name=on"
unechecked boxes are not passed at all.

Comment: Yeah, if you use a POST, you actually get all the checkbox status' + their names. But ti works with GET as well, just add the names to the URL you GET so you can extract the names. If the order of the attributes is fixed, even ju7st a number will suffice. Can you show the code that creates the URL you GET to pass the values?

Comment: its just a HTML form with an action.
so the url is "[...]?searchString=test&name=on" after submit with "name" checked.

Comment: You can extract `name` from the string `name=on` to know that the name checkbox is checked.

Comment: You can either extract `name` yourself, or use `new URLSearchParams()` and it's methods to do it for you.

Comment: okay, I thought that I can do something like "var nameIsChecked = data.request.get.name" and then access the "name" to put it in the selected_attributes by acces "nameIsChecked.value" or ".name" or something.

Comment: That purely depends on your server infrastructure. You probably can do that, but I cannot tell you which syntax to use without knowing how your server works. Is it a node.js express server? Is it a php server? Something else? So I would have to know which data.request documentation to look at. :)

Answer (score 0):

write a function.

```js
recipes.filter(e => {
  if (whatever) return true;
  else {
    // additional checks.
  }
});
```

in your case, I guess something like this:

```js
recipes.filter(e => {
  if (ingredientsAreChecked()) {
    return e.name.matchesSearchString() || e.ingredients.some(i => i.matchesSearchString());
  }
  else {
    return e.name.matchesSearchString();
  }
});
```

or if `ingredientsAreChecked()` is not a computationally light thing to do, then do something like this:

```js
if (ingredientsAreChecked()) return recipes.filter(e => ...);
else return recipes.filter(e => ...);
```

Comment: thank you. But if there are 4 checkboxes which can be checked or unchecked I would need to handle EVERY possible combination of true and false, right?

Comment: @DannyBergs yes if the conditions are complicated then I would suggest the first solution, i.e. writing a function that reflects that complicated logic. and also I'm afraid there is no work-around in that case, IF the logic of matching a recipe is complicated then the filter function will look complicated as well, precisely as complicated as the filtering logic.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is a higher order function that takes a predicate function that either returns `true` or `false` depending on the current item should be kept or not. In your case the function is a single one-liner, but any kind of function could be passed.

So if you have complex logic, I suggest that you move it out into a named function, where you can check for several conditions, and finally return a single boolean value:

```
function isRecipeValid(recipe) {
  if (recipe.something) return false;
  // any arbitrary conditional checking here
  return recipe.conditionOne && recipe.conditionTwo;
}

recipes.filter(isRecipeValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have two things: search term *and* fields to search.

You can build a filtering function that takes those two, and a single record (single recipe) and returns true or false.

Say your checkboxes are `name`, `description`, `ingreedients`.

What you do is you send your filter function the item name, but also the name of the fields you wanna search. Then insert the values there.

You could have something like this:

```js
// Disclaimer: these recipes are made up
const recipes = [{
    name: 'lemon cake',
    description: 'a delicious cake',
    ingreedients: ['lemon', 'flour', 'sugar'],
  },
  {
    name: 'sour lemon cake',
    description: 'a delicious cake',
    ingreedients: ['lemon', 'flour', 'not sugar'],
  },
  {
    name: 'choco brownie',
    description: 'a sweet chocolate desert',
    ingreedients: ['chocolate', 'milk', 'flour', 'salt', 'sugar'],
  },
  {
    name: 'vanilla croissant',
    description: 'a yummy pastry with vanilla flavour',
    ingreedients: ['vanilla', 'milk', 'flour'],
  }
];

// To search, we need the search term, and an array of fields by which to search
// We return ANY match, meaning if the search term is in any of the fields, it's a match
function searchAnyField(searchTerm, searchFields) {
  return recipes.filter(item => {
    for (let field of searchFields) {
      if (item[field].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}

// the same, but we make sure the search term exists in ALL fields (seems dumb here, but could be a req)
function searchAllFields(searchTerm, searchFields) {
  return recipes.filter(item => {
    // A naive approach is to count in how many fields did we find the term and if it matches the search fields length
    let foundInFields = 0;
    for (let field of searchFields) {
      if (item[field].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
        foundInFields++;
      }
    }
    return foundInFields === searchFields.length;
  });
}

// Let's see it in action
// we'lll just print out the names of found items
console.log('Brownie in name:', printNames(
  searchAnyField('brownie', ['name'])));
console.log('Cake in name:', printNames(
  searchAnyField('cake', ['name'])));
// Let's try multiple fields
console.log('Choc in name and desc:', printNames(
  searchAnyField('choc', ['name', 'description'])));
console.log('flour anywhere:', printNames(
  searchAnyField('flour', ['name', 'description', 'ingreedients'])));
console.log('sweet anywhere:', printNames(
  searchAnyField('sweet', ['name', 'description', 'ingreedients'])));

// How about AND search:
console.log('cake in name AND desc:', printNames(
  searchAllFields('cake', ['name', 'description'])));
console.log('cake everywhere:', printNames(
  searchAllFields('cake', ['name', 'description', 'ingreedients'])));



function printNames(recipes) {
  return recipes.map(r => r.name).join(', ');
}
```

---

Edit: You also said you have some nested props and whatnot. Here are more examples of how you could go about it.

```js
const FIELDS = {
  name: {
    type: 'string',
    path: 'name',
  },
  description: {
    type: 'string',
    path: 'name',
  },
  ingreedients: {
    type: 'array',
    path: 'name',
  },
  price: {
    type: 'nested',
    path: 'details.price',
    nestedType: 'number',
  }
}

// Disclaimer: these recipes are made up
const recipes = [{
    name: 'lemon cake',
    description: 'a delicious cake',
    ingreedients: ['lemon', 'flour', 'sugar'],
    details: {
      price: 45,
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'sour lemon cake',
    description: 'a delicious cake',
    ingreedients: ['lemon', 'flour', 'not sugar'],
    details: {
      price: 45,
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'choco brownie',
    description: 'a sweet chocolate desert',
    ingreedients: ['chocolate', 'milk', 'flour', 'salt', 'sugar'],
    details: {
      price: 42,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'vanilla croissant',
    description: 'a yummy pastry with vanilla flavour',
    ingreedients: ['vanilla', 'milk', 'flour'],
    details: {
      price: 45,
    },
  }
];

// To search, we need the search term, and an array of fields by which to search
// We return ANY match, meaning if the search term is in any of the fields, it's a match
function searchAnyField(searchTerm, searchFields) {
  return recipes.filter(item => {
    for (let field of searchFields) {
      switch (field.type) {
        case 'string':
          if (item[field.path].indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
            return true;
          }
        case 'array':
          if (item[field.path].includes(searchTerm) > -1) {
            return true;
          }
        case 'nested':
          const props = field.path.split('.').reverse();
          let prop = props.pop();
          let val = item[prop];
          while (val && props.length > 0) {
            prop = props.pop();
            val = val[prop]
          }
          if (field.nestedType === 'string') {
            if (val && val.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
              return true;
            }
          } else if (field.nestedType === 'number') {
            return val == searchTerm;
          }
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}


// Let's see it in action
// we'lll just print out the names of found items
console.log('42 anywhere:', printNames(
  searchAnyField(42, [ FIELDS.price])));
  
console.log('42 anywhere:', printNames(
  searchAnyField(42, [ FIELDS.price, FIELDS.name])));




function printNames(recipes) {
  return recipes.map(r => r.name).join(', ');
}
```

Comment: thank you for your huge and helpfull answer.
There is a problem I need to handle I think.

The ingredients are an array of objects, becuase every ingredient is made of "name", "amount" and "unit".

Comment: @DannyBergs at least you get the principle. Lemme see about the ingreedients.